# Ordered dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to create a method that displays dictionaries keys in a numbered list.  I chose to use a dictionary because there is a lot of data stored in the key's value (as a list) which is not displayed here.
eg:
1. Bob
2. Simon
3. Phil

I did this with a simple for loop.

```
if self.caseload:
     i = 1
     print ""
     for name in self.caseload:
          print "%d. %s" % (i, name)
          i += 1
```

I then want a user to be able to select one of these keys using either its assigned name (pretty simple) or the number assigned to it.  This is where I run into trouble. Since the dictionary is unordered and the numbers are assigned on the fly, I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are not adding or removing keys from your dictionary, the order of the keys remains *stable*.

You can index the `dict.keys()` list, it'll still have the same order as when you displayed the keys:

```
key = self.caseload.keys()[int(userchoice) - 1]
```

As Python lists are indexed starting from 0, you'll have to translate user input by subtracting 1.

Instead of using a manual count, consider using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to number the keys when printing your menu:

```
if self.caseload:
     print ""
     for i, name in enumerate(self.caseload, 1):
          print "%d. %s" % (i, name)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I had no idea dictionaries would maintain any sort of order even in a temporary context.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [OrderDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)

> Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they remember the order that items were inserted

Also you can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get index of item while iterating

`for i, name in enumarate(self.caseload, start=1):
    print "%d. %s" % (i, name)`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to go about this.

You could create a new dict to link the numbers to the names;

```
In [2]: d = {'Bob': 'foo', 'Simon': 'bar', 'Phil': 'baz'}

In [3]: e = {n: v for n, v in zip(range(1, len(d)+1), d.keys())}

In [4]: e
Out[4]: {1: 'Bob', 2: 'Simon', 3: 'Phil'}
```

Or you could link the numbers directly to the values of the dictionary;

```
In [5]: f = {n: v for n, v in zip(range(1, len(d)+1), d.values())}

In [6]: f
Out[6]: {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar', 3: 'baz'}
```

Check if the input is a number; if so you can use the dict `e` to get the name, or you can use `f` to get the value.